# How to display only few HeadRow information from API data in React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I get API data to display information using React Table library. Data is suited for desktop displayed information, for mobile screen I need only part of it. In mobile I want to display only below marked HeadRows. Can You please advise how can I achieve that and pick only those two out of all ?
[image]

this is how implementation looks like:

```
const columns: Column<TransformedData>[] = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: symbolTxt,
                accessor: 'symbol',
                collapse: true,
                maxWidth: 135,
                minWidth: 135,
                width: 135,
            },
            {
                Header: parameterTxt,
                accessor: 'parameter',
                collapse: true,
                maxWidth: 260,
                minWidth: 260,
                width: 260,
            }]),
```

I should replace accessor with data which will point to index 2 and use data to next headerRow, and then next accessor from index 6

thanks

Comment: do just need index 2 and 6 or if isHeaderRow is true??

Comment: I have tried to access it but failed. I have updated the question with implementation code

Comment: your library is this? : https://react-table.tanstack.com/  have you checked if it has hidden attribute?